# How to open comport using vb script

Tags: vbscript

I am currently developing a POS in web based . Now i want to connect custmor display for that so i want to open comport using vb script.

so anyone help me how can open comport using vb script?

Thanking You

Comment: Why are you using VBScript? Classic ASP is deprecated (last updated in 1999 for Windows 2000) and IE11 does not support VBScript.

Comment: ok thanks how can i connect customer display for web based POS system?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't - there is no way to access the serial port through a web-browser unless you use an ActiveX control - and if you do that then you're limited to Windows. Java browser Applets cannot access the serial port.